# Userform won't loop through 'for loop' outlining userform controls' requirements

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Userform where operator has to input info into 4 Textboxes, cleverly named TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, and TextBox4.

Each TextBox requires a unique format and I need to ensure that the info entered into each Textbox is valid.

I placed a 'For Each "Ctrl" In Me.Controls' Loop within my OKButton_Click() command with the hope that the program will verify all the info entered before the userform "accepts" the info and unloads.

When I run the program, I cannot get the program to execute the loop. It instead goes around it.

I've double checked the number of EndIf statements I need and it should be good to go.

```
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()
Dim Ctrl As Control

For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
     If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox1" Then
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Only numbers allowed in Quantity section."
            TextBox1.Value = ""
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
            If TextBox1.TextLength > 3 Or TextBox1.Value = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Quantity invalid."
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf TextBox1.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Need a quantity value."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox2" Then
        If TextBox2.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You must enter a value for Shop Order."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox3" Then
        If TextBox3.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You must enter a value for Heat Number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox4" Then
        If IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) Then
            MsgBox "No numbers allowed in Initials Section"
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) Then
            If TextBox4.TextLength > 3 Or TextBox4.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Enter 3 digit Initials"
            TextBox4.Value = ""
            Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl


MsgBox "Values successfully checked"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

I run the userform from within the excel file, leave the textboxes empty, click the OkButton, and the MsgBox "Values successfully checked" appears.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Comment: `TypeName` returns the *type* of the control.  It does not return its Name property.  Seems like you should be checking `Ctrl.Name` instead

Comment: And a follow-up question: If you're going to hard-code the names of the controls, why do you need the loop in the first place? Just validate the controls directly without the loop and `TypeName()` call.

Comment: It should be `If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox"` and you can use it for looping through all textboxes. To check for individual Textboxe's names, use `Ctrl.Name`. BTW for 4 textboxes, you can directly handle them like @KenWhite mentioned. No need for a loop...

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I changed the If statements to  'Ctrl.Name'